# probability vs combinatorics interpretation of problems

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I have some difficulty to pass from a combinatorics solution of a problem to a faster possible solution with just the use of probability . For example :

100 people seat at random on a plane with 100 seats while they also have a ticket with an assigned seat , what is the probability to seat on your assigned seat if you are the 34th to get on the plane?

If you think about it with combinatorics it is simple to come up with the right answer : there is just a place where you can seat and 99! ways to put the rest of people while the total number of possible arrangements is 100! so the answer is 1/100

But I find it more difficult to think about it in terms of probability and so to get the same answer with 'less' effort (if I'm the 34th to seat how can the probability stay the same as if I was the first one?)

Comment: Do you mean 34 degrees Fahrenheit or Celsius? +1 for correction.

Comment: I'm not used to the english notation ahah

Comment: Everything is fine and you´ve got a perfect answer from kccu. The key point is the cancelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a probabilistic point of view, the event that I, as the 34th passenger, sit in my correct seat is the same as the event that I sit in my correct seat, and nobody before me sits in my seat. Let $A_i$ be the event that passenger $i$ does not sit in my seat, and $B$ be the event that I do sit in my seat. Then we want:
$$P(A_1\cap A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_{33} \cap B).$$
We can expand this as
$$P(A_1)P(A_2\mid A_1)\cdots P(A_{33}\mid A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_{32})P(B \mid A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_{33}).$$
Since there are $100$ seats and $99$ of them are not mine, $P(A_1 ) = 99/100$. Given $A_1$ (i.e., passenger 1 did not sit in my seat), there are now $99$ unoccupied seats and $98$ unoccupied seats that are not mine, so $P(A_2 \mid A_1) = 98/99$. Similarly, $P(A_3 \mid A_1 \cap A_2) = 97/98$, and so on. The 33rd person has $68$ unoccupied seats to choose from, of which $67$ are not mine, so $P(A_{33} \mid A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_{32}) = 67/68$.

Finally, we need $P(B \mid A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_{33}$). We are given that $33$ people sat in seats that were not mine. So there are $67$ unoccupied seats, one of which is mine, so this probability is $1/67$. Putting it all together we have:
$$\frac{99}{100}\cdot \frac{98}{99} \cdots \frac{67}{68}\cdot \frac{1}{67} = \frac{1}{100}.$$

Comment: I think the problem is easier once you realize that the probability of sitting in your assigned seat is the same regardless of position due to symmetry, so consider the probability of the very first person sitting in their assigned seat.

Comment: @DonThousand But to prove the existence of this symmetry, don't you need to go exactly kccu's way?

Comment: @Sudix I don't think so. I can't go into full detail in the comments, but if you consider the set of all 100 person permutations, for every permutation with you in seat 1, there are 99 others with you not in seat 1. That doesn't require this detailed an answer.

Comment: @DonThousand That's essentially the combinatorics argument that OP gave. Which is also a probabilistic argument, just one by counting arrangements rather than thinking about events happening sequentially.

Comment: @kccu I think we are just violently agreeing. I understand where you are coming from, but I respectfully disagree. I don't think OP's argument has the necessary rigor to be valid.

Comment: @DonThousand What is non-rigorous about OP's argument? They count the number of ways the people can board the plane with you in your correct seat ($99!$) and the total number of ways everyone can board the plane ($100!$). These are all equally likely, so the probability you get your seat is $99!/100!=1/100$.

Comment: @kccu I'd say what's missing is a proof that if every person sits randomly, all permutations are equally likely.

Comment: @Sudix Okay sure. In any case, OP wanted an answer that *didn't* involve counting permutations, so that's what I gave.